# Qt 5.15 QML Project FileDialog Binding loop Warning

Tags: c++, qt, qml, filedialog

Hi I am working on a QML project now with Qt 5.15 version. The problem is that the following Binding loop warning occurs in the FileDialog I declared.

" ~~ QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml:413:17: QML ToolButton: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight""

" ~~ QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml:309:21: QML Button: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight""

" ~~ QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml:309:21: QML Button: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight""

this is my FileDialog

```
FileDialog 
{

    id: myFileDialogId

    folder: myProperty

    onAccepted: {

        Action~~

        myProperty = fileUrl

    }

    onRejected: {

    }

}
```

Any solution?

I want to get rid of all these warnings.

Comment: Can you show the code where you use this FileDialog? I guess, it has more to do with the way you are using it.

Comment: Easiest way to break the binding loop is to (1) remove `folder: myProperty`, and optionally (2) add `Component.onCompleted: folder = myProperty`

Comment: As to why you're getting implicitWidth and implicitHeight issues, you need to provide the additional context of the code surrounding your FileDialog.